# React, Ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, reactjs, ember-data

I use ember-data in my ember.js projects, now I learn react.
My question is: what technics are used in react to achieve the same functionality as ember-data?
I'd like to:

1. have something like models
2. if I've changed model in one place,
   changes are visible in other component
3. have some model's methods
   like:

   fullName(){ return this.get('name')+' '+this.get('secondName'); }

Comment: Based upon my limited knowledge, React has nothing like ember data.

Comment: What does ember-data give you that you can't achieve using POJO and React?

Answer (score 4):

`ember-data` is a library, that handles remote data retrieve/send operations. To handle those remote operations, `ember-data` provides models, adapters, serializers etc. Btw, `ember-data` is an implementation of [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org).

`ember-data` description from the [README.md](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/README.md):

> ember-data is a library for robustly managing data in applications
>   built with Ember.js.
>
> ...
>
> It provides many of the facilities you'd find in server-side ORMs like...

So, if you search it through google with "**react orm**", you can find some libraries, such as:

- [redux-orm](https://github.com/redux-orm/redux-orm)
- [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/)

And if you visit [JSON:API implementations page](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/), you can find other libraries that implements the JSON:API and plays well with redux or react.